# Wireframe mode doesn't select everything

Tags: selection-tools, wireframe

I had this feature until I must've clicked on something. But on wireframe mode, when i'm trying to select trough everything, it doesn't..react same way as if it was in solid mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably disabled X-Ray mode.
It's enabled by default, but can be switched off/on.

[image]

Comment: YES @JACHYM i feel stupid now....THANK YOU

Comment: Happy to help. And don't feel bad, at least you learned something new :).

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you're in edit mode or object mode. If necessary hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to go to Edit mode